# Countif but only the first 5 occupied cells in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I want a formula ( maybe COUNTIF? ) to count how many "**W**" and "**D**" and "**L**" are found per each range: `B3:B12`, `D3:D12` and `F3:F12`.

But to count only in the first 5 cells with value (that are NOT empty blank cells).

I don't want to count all "**W**" and "**D**" and "**L**" found in the entire range.

I want to count "**W**" and "**D**" and "**L**" on the first 5 filled cells, skiping the blank cells.

The formulas must be separate, meaning a formula to count just the value "**W**", another formula to count just the value "**D**", another formula to count just the value "**L**".

In short, to count in the first 5 cells that are not blank:

- How many "**W**"
- How many "**D**"
- How many "**L**"

I want to obtain the count from the green examples.

I DO NOT want to obtain the count from the red examples.

Please see attached image. Thank you !
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EZ8O.png]

Comment: =countif(B3:b12,"L") then edit and repeat for the other letters and ranges. Excel shows some good examples in the help. But use indirect() to control the range to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX and AGGREGATE:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(B3:B12)/(B3:B12<>""),5)),"W")
```

Then you can change the `W` to what ever else and the range to the range you want.

[image]

Comment: Mr Scott Craner THANK YOU very much ! This is exactly what I wanted ! You are great ! God Bless You All !